# cosine similarity between a vector and pandas column(a linear vector)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, array-broadcasting

I have a pandas data frame containing list of wines with their respective wine attributes.

Then I made a new column vector that contains numpy vectors from these attributes.

```
def get_wine_profile(id):
wine = wines[wines['exclusiviId'] == id]
wine_vector = np.array(wine[wine_attrs].values.tolist()).flatten()

return wine_vector

wines['vector'] = wines.exclusiviId.apply(get_wine_profile)
```

hence the vector column look something like this

```
vector

[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]

[3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3]

[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1]

.

.
```

now I want to perform cosine similarity between this column and another vector that is resulting vector from the user input
This is what i have tried so far

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
cos_vec = wines.apply(lambda x: (1-cosine(wines["vector"],[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]), axis=1)
Print(cos_vec)
```

this is throwing error

```
ValueError: ('operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (63,) (10,) ', 'occurred at index 0')
```

I also tries using sklearn but it also have the same problem with the arrar shape

what i want as a final output is a column that has match score between this column and user input

Answer (score 0):

A better solution IMO is to use `cdist` with `cosine` metric. You are effectively computing pairwise distances between `n` points in your DataFrame and `1` point in your user input, i.e. `n` pairs in total.

If you handle more than one user at a time, this would be even more efficient.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# make into 1x10 array
user_input = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])[None]
df["cos_dist"] = cdist(np.stack(df.vector), user_input, metric="cosine")


# vector  cos_dist
# 0  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]   0.00000
# 1  [3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3]   0.15880
# 2  [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1]   0.07613
```

By the way, it looks like you are using native Python lists. I would switch everything to numpy arrays. A conversion to `np.array` is happening under the hood anyway when you call `cosine`.

Comment: thanks, @yakym for the answer but i already tried a different approach which worked

Answer (score 0):

well i made my own function to do this and yes it works

```
import math
def cosine_similarity(v1,v2):
"compute cosine similarity of v1 to v2: (v1 dot v2)/{||v1||*||v2||)"
sumxx, sumxy, sumyy = 0, 0, 0
for i in range(len(v1)):
    x = v1[i]; y = v2[i]
    sumxx += x*x
    sumyy += y*y
    sumxy += x*y
return sumxy/math.sqrt(sumxx*sumyy)

def get_similarity(id):
 vec1 = result_vector
 vec2 = get_wine_profile(id)
 similarity = cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2)
 return similarity

wines['score'] = wines.exclusiviId.apply(get_similarity)
display(wines.head())
```